# Error in login app (JavaFX -eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, javafx, authentication

I'm trying to create a simple JavaFX application for login and I'm getting the following error (s):

javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/iulia/universitate/an%20I,%20semestrul%20II/POO/Proiect/POO/bin/application/Loggin.fxml:10

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
at om.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TextField field application.Login.usersg to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

Here is my code:

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Login {
 @FXML
 private Label lblog;
 @FXML
 private Label lbmem;
 @FXML
 private TextField user;
 @FXML
 private TextField name;
 @FXML
 private TextField lname;
 @FXML
 private TextField usersg;
 @FXML
 private PasswordField paswd;
 @FXML

 private PasswordField paswdsg;
 @FXML
 private PasswordField paswdsga;
private Client client;

 public void log(ActionEvent event)
 {
     if(user.getText().equals("Iulia") && paswd.getText().equals("1234"))
         lblog.setText("Login successful");
     else
         lblog.setText("Login failed. Username and password don't match");
 }

package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root= FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Loggin.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

FMXL resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" text="WELCOME TO PAY-APP" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Login">
  <content>
    <AnchorPane fx:id="usersg" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblog" layoutX="43.0" layoutY="43.0" text="LOG IN " textAlignment="CENTER" />
            <TextField fx:id="user" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="74.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="paswd" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="131.0" />
            <Button fx:id="logbt" layoutX="152.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#log" text="LOG IN" />
            <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="78.0" text="USERNAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="135.0" text="PASSWORD:" />
            <Button fx:id="sgnbt" layoutX="377.0" layoutY="280.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="SIGN UP!" />
            <Label fx:id="lbmem" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="43.0" text="NOT A MEMBER? SIGN UP!" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="78.0" text="NAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="111.0" text="LAST NAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="288.0" layoutY="148.0" text="USERNAME:" />
            <Label layoutX="287.0" layoutY="189.0" text="PASSWORD:" />
            <Label layoutX="287.0" layoutY="231.0" text="PASSWORD AGAIN:" />
            <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="66.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="usersg" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="144.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="lname" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="107.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="paswdsg" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="185.0" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="pswdsga" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="227.0" />
         </children></AnchorPane>
  </content>
</TitledPane>
```

and MainFX.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</AnchorPane>
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the FXML resource as well?

Comment: In your FXML, `usersg` is an AnchorPane. Where as in your controller, it is a TextField defined by `@FXML private TextField usersg;`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your FXML, `usersg` is an AnchorPane.

Where as in your controller, `usersg` is defined as an `TextField` by:

```
@FXML
private TextField usersg;
```

Just change the definition to AnchorPane and it should work :

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane usersg;
```